# Change column in dataframe where

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to change one column in an R-dataframe if some column has a specific content (however, not the exact content, rather a content I find with Regex).

For example:

```
 df:
 Name        City            Age
 Peter       Fort Wayne      15
 John        South Bend      20
 Christopher Boston          25
 Andy        Boston          30
 Johnathan   Los Angeles     35
```

Now, if I want to change the age of all people whose names begin with John, I would usually select them by saying:

```
 subset(df, grepl("^John", Name))
```

Which would give me

```
 Name        City            Age
 John        South Bend      20
 Johnathan   Los Angeles     35
```

However, apparently I cannot change it using

```
 subset(df, grepl("^John", Name))$Age <- 20
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I'd hate to drop the rows from the dataframe and then re-insert them, which is what I've been doing so far.

Thanks for your help,
Oliver

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
 df$Age[grepl("^John", df$Name)] <- 20
```

`subset` returns a `data.frame` and you can not assign `20` to the whole `data.frame`. Instead, index by columns as shown above.

Comment: When I do this and assign a character/string, it tells me "invalid factor level, NAs generated". Any ideas?

Comment: oliver, please edit your original post using `dput(head(df))` for me to work on the data to figure out what's the problem.